# How Can i pass data with localstorage?

Tags: javascript, html

Hello  I'm trying to move the content in the data box to the next page. For some reason the content is not working. I went through the code several times and could not find where the problem is. I would be happy to help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: if you make a jsfiddle, it will be easier to help you (https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You could not see the value in the localStorage in DevTools?

Answer (score 1):

you must first turn the data that you want to save into a string, use JSON:

```
localStorage.setItem("textvalue",JSON.stringify(firstname));
```

and when you want to read the data, parse it so its back to its original form

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("textvalue"))
```

The reason is that localStorage only accepts stringed values, i hope this helps

Comment: I COPIED IT TO THE CODE AND IT STILL DOSNT WORK..:(

Comment: Put the script after the body tag

Answer (score 0):

It could be the case that your non-closed form tag caused the issue - you have two options:
remove the `<form>` tag or add closing `</form>` tag.